# Are there any specific rules to follow when converting from Guice DI to Hilt/Dagger DI

Tags: android, dependency-injection, guice, dagger, dagger-hilt

So I just want to convert this app I have from Guice DI to Hilt/DI.
I could stick up and read through all the documentation. But I'm just looking for the fast way around.
It would be awesome if you know of a simple step by step process which could help anyone convert Guice to Dagger/Hilt.
If we got such a solid method for this conversion, I was thinking ... why not automate it.